# Two or more tabs section activated only with css and html

Tags: html, css

atm I need to have 3-4 tabs section on the same HTML document, but duplicating this snippet doesnt work. Also I've changed all the class names and it still doesnt work.

I want all of them to be open at its first tab. Not only one section open at time.

This is what I need: [the idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXDt3.png) and this is what I am getting: [the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWzCq.png)

```
/*
 CSS for the main interaction
*/
.tabset > input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -200vw;
}
.tabset2 > .input2[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -200vw;
}

.tabset .tab-panel {
  display: none;
}
.tabset2 .tab-panel2 {
  display: none;
}

.tabset > input:first-child:checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:first-child,
.tabset > input:nth-child(3):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(2),
.tabset > input:nth-child(5):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(3),
.tabset > input:nth-child(7):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(4),
.tabset > input:nth-child(9):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(5),
.tabset > input:nth-child(11):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(6) {
  display: block;
}
.tabset2 > .input2:first-child:checked ~ .tab-panels2 > .tab-panel2:first-child,
.tabset2 > .input2:nth-child(3):checked ~ .tab-panels2 > .tab-panel2:nth-child(2),
.tabset2 > .input2:nth-child(5):checked ~ .tab-panels2 > .tab-panel2:nth-child(3),
.tabset2 > .input2:nth-child(7):checked ~ .tab-panels2 > .tab-panel2:nth-child(4),
.tabset2 > .input2:nth-child(9):checked ~ .tab-panels2 > .tab-panel2:nth-child(5),
.tabset2 > .input2:nth-child(11):checked ~ .tab-panels2 > .tab-panel2:nth-child(6) {
  display: block;
}

/*
 Styling
*/
body {
  font: 16px/1.5em "Overpass", "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.tabset > label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 15px 25px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.tabset2 > .label2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 15px 25px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.tabset > label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #8d8d8d;
}
.tabset2 > .label2::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #8d8d8d;
}

.tabset > label:hover,
.tabset > input:focus + label {
  color: #06c;
}
.tabset2 > .label2:hover,
.tabset2 > .input2:focus + .label2 {
  color: #06c;
}

.tabset > label:hover::after,
.tabset > input:focus + label::after,
.tabset > input:checked + label::after {
  background: #06c;
}
.tabset2 > .label2:hover::after,
.tabset2 > .input2:focus + .label2::after,
.tabset2 > .input2:checked + .label2::after {
  background: #06c;
}

.tabset > input:checked + label {
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.tabset2 > .input2:checked + .label2 {
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.tab-panel {
  padding: 30px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tab-panel2 {
  padding: 30px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

As you can see, I have duplicated the classes to look if it works with two checked tabs, but It doesnt work. The most I can get is to have they both working, but not at the same time.

You can see the complete code in this codepen: [Snippet link](https://codepen.io/sgarcia710/pen/eYOeLBZ?editors=1100). Thanks for the help. I am really lost trying to have these sections, first time doing it, hahaha.

Comment: You have all your inputs with the same `name` property of `tabset` so they're all part essentially part of the same `group`, just change the `name` attribute on the other "tabsets" to like `name="tabset2"` (like you did with the css class name that contains them) you have and it will work as expected; [like this](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/jONaeqy?editors=1100)

Comment: @ChrisW. It was so easy!!! God. Thanks so much for your help. Really!

Comment: No worries, we've all been there.